# ASP.NET MVC Security Recommendations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

I have recently started a personal project that uses ASP.NET MVC (RC1 at the time of writing). My background is traditional ASP.NET WebForms development.

My knowledge ASP.NET MVC is limited, so I would like your input on how to best approach authentication, input validation and protection against common attacks (XSS, XSRF, etc).

I’ll start by listing a few articles [Stephen Walther posted on his blog](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/):

- [Tip #7 - Prevent JavaScript Injection Attacks with Html.Encode](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/06/23/asp-net-mvc-tip-7-prevent-javascript-injection-attacks-with-html-encode.aspx)
- [Tip #10 - Prevent URL Manipulation Attacks](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/06/26/prevent-url-manipulation-attacks.aspx)
- [Tip #46 – Don’t use Delete Links because they create Security Holes](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/01/21/asp.net-mvc-tip-46-ndash-donrsquot-use-delete-links-because.aspx)

Validation:

- [xVal Validation Framework](http://www.codeplex.com/xval)

Thanks, 
Arnie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Off the top of my head (and nowhere near complete)...

- Use the AntiForgeryToken on all forms to protect against XSRF.  Use unit tests to make sure that all controller actions that accept POSTS are decorated with the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute.
- Make use of HtmlHelper extensions whereever possible to take advantage of automatic HTML encoding.
- Use an ORM with parameterized queries for all DB access -- not unique to MVC, but still relevant.
- Be restrictive in the HTTP verbs that you accept to the minimum required.  Use DELETE (vi AJAX) or POST for delete actions.
- Use the AuthorizeAttribute, or an attribute derived from it, to protect non-public actions.
- Don't expose user ids/passwords in urls which might be cached (i.e., login via form POST rather than GET url).  As always, use SSL for passing sensitive data.